# how split sentence and let only ascii characters

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, search

i want to split a sentence to convert the words into tags (to make a simple full text search in `Mongodb`), and i dont want to save comma or colon :

```
phrase = "hello, this is a simple description!"
pattern  = "[\"\'\!\?\:\,\;]"
```

i've tried this:

```
re.split(pattern, phrase)
Out[1]: ['hello', ' this is a simple description', ''] # as you can see, i've always blank characters.
```

i want to remove all "non letters characters", there is `phrase.replace(",", " ")` but replaces only one character, so how do i use the regular expression with replace? sssomething like `re.remove(pattern, phrase)`, is there is a loop, does this become a heavy work to the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`non-regex` solution:
use `strip()`, but you need to pass all the non-letter characters to it.

something like: `strip(',!*&^%#$;:+')`

```
In [12]: phrase = "hello, this is: a simple; description!!"
In [13]:  [x.strip(',!*&^%#$;:+') for x in phrase.split()]

Out[13]: ['hello', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'simple', 'description']
```

Comment: ah!!! that is what i need! because i'll use also unicode characters (arabic, french, tifinagh(amazigh) ...)

Answer (score 2):

If you split on non-word characters `\W` that should leave you with an array of only words.

Comment: but i'll deal with unicode characters, will this include them?

Comment: so long as you have the LOCALE & UNICODE properly set, then yes